# adjusting manipulate output in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need help. I have many variables, that I use in my `Graphics[]` command, that are dependent of one variable (H in my example). I want to manipulate my graphic so that by changing value of H graphic changes accordingly. But it is not as easy as I've thought.

If you have any idea on how to acomplish this, I would be grateful.

```
 (*This variables are dependent on H that I want to change in
manipulate*)

R = 10;

\[Alpha] = ArcSin[H/R];

p = H/Tan[\[Alpha]];

n = 1.5;

\[Beta] = ArcSin[n Sin[\[Alpha]]];

\[Theta] = \[Beta] - \[Alpha];

l = H/Tan[\[Theta]];

(*This is the graphic I want to make manipulated*)

Graphics[{(*Incident ray*)Line[{{-2, H}, {p, H}}],(*Prism*)
  Circle[{0, 0}, R, {0, Pi/2}], 
  Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 10}}],(*Refracted ray*)
  Line[{{p, H}, {p + l, 0}}],(*Surface*)
  Line[{{0, 0}, {p + l + 10, 0}}]}]
```

Here's one of my solutions but it's really messy. What I did is just manually pluged in those values. Is there any more appropriate way to acomplish this:

```
R = 10;
n = 1.5;
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{(*Incident ray*)
   Line[{{-2, H}, {H/Tan[ArcSin[H/10]], H}}],(*Prism*)
   Circle[{0, 0}, R, {0, Pi/2}], 
   Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 10}}],(*Refracted ray*)
   Line[{{H/Tan[ArcSin[H/10]], 
      H}, {H/Tan[ArcSin[H/10]] + 
       H/Tan[ArcSin[n Sin[ArcSin[H/10]]] - ArcSin[H/10]], 
      0}}],(*Surface*)
   Line[{{0, 
      0}, {H/Tan[ArcSin[H/10]] + 
       H/Tan[ArcSin[n Sin[ArcSin[H/10]]] - ArcSin[H/10]] + 10, 
      0}}]}], {H, 0.0001, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

And also how to make my graphic **not to change it's size** constantly. I want prism to have fixed size and incident ray to change its position (as it happens when H gets > 6.66 in my example above / this solution).

The question is maybe confusing, but if you try it in Mathematica, you'll see what I want. Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your solution is not bad in general, Mark already noticed in his reply. I loved simplicity of Mark's solution too. Just for the sake of experiment I share my ideas too.

1) It is always a good thing to localize your variables for a specific Manipulate, so their values do not leak and interfere with other dynamic content. It matters if you have additional computation in your notebook - they may start resetting each other.

2) In this particular case if you try to get read of extra variables plugging expressions one into each other your equations became complicated and it is hard to see why they would fail some times. A bit of algebra with help of functions TrigExpand and FullSimplify may help to clarify that your variable H has limitations depending on refraction index value n (see below).

3) If we are aware of point (2) we can make variable n dynamic too and link the value H to n (resetting upper bound of H) right in the controls definition, so always it should be H<10/n . If[..] is also necessary so the controls will not “pink”.

4) If your formulas would depend on R we could also make R dynamic. But I do not have this information, so I localized R via concept of a “dummy“ control (ControlType -> None) – which is quite useful concept for Manipulate.

5) Use PlotRange and ImageSize to stop jiggling of graphics

6) Make it beautiful ;-)

These points would be important if you’d like, for example, to submit a Demonstration  to the Wolfram Demonstration Project. If you are just playing around – I think yours and Mark’s solutions are very good.

Thanks,
Vitaliy

```
 Manipulate[If[H >= 10/n, H = 10/n - .0001]; Graphics[{
   {Red, Thick, Line[{{-2, H}, {Sqrt[100 - H^2], H}}]},
   {Blue, Opacity[.5], Disk[{0, 0}, R, {0, Pi/2}]},
   {Red, Thick, Line[{{Sqrt[100 - H^2], H}, 
    {(100 n)/(Sqrt[100 - H^2] n - Sqrt[100 - H^2 n^2]), 0}}]}},
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 10}}, 
  ImageSize -> {600, 200}], {{R, 10}, ControlType -> None},
 {{n, 1.5, "Refraction"}, 1.001, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{H, 3, "Length"}, 0.0001, 10/n - .0001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: By the way I removed a few stationary lines from your code - it is easy to put them back.

Comment: I haven't looked through in detail, but there seem to be a small bug. The "Length" slider doesn't stop at `10/n`. If you go past it, it slips back to 0.0001. Similarly, if you increase the "Refraction" slider such that the length > `10/n`, then the length slips back to 0, but the slider is free to move. I know the physics of it and why it happens, but it might be better if the slider stopped, instead of either resetting/moving freely. In any case, welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for committing to the proposal :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, Yoda, and thanks for the warm welcome. I adjusted code a bit.

Comment: When I saw, what you did, I said waoo. It's awesome. In fact I made this code just to solve physics problem, but now I think to publish it. Of course if it's ok with you? I have one more question. I used Export[] to export this manipulate animation as swf, but I cannot publish it on our physics group on facebook, because that format is not supported. Also if I export it as avi (it has less quality) but then neither fb, nor youtube cannot process it. If you have any idea how to show this animation to users that don't have cdf player, nor mathematica?

Comment: And I forgot to say, Thank you!

Comment: I am absolutely fine with you using it anyhow you wish ;) The best solution of course is *still* a live CDF embed into HTML page. If they do not have CDF player they will be automatically redirected to download it and the plugin (on most OS systems). Facebook a bit more difficult - could be just a URL link pointing to where live CDF lives. If you still want an alternative option that can be showcased  even on Facebook - maybe just animated .GIF will do. Use Table[] instead of Manipulate to make list of images with smoothly changing parameters. Then Export["path/my.gif", list]

Comment: Although I don't have a clue how to achieve this with table, I like the idea. I'll check some tutorials and (I'll keep refraction as constant for sake of problem and simplicity).

Comment: Read this: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/GIF.html Also below is simple code as an example how to make animated .GIF . It will save the animated image into the same directory where you Mathematica notebook with the code is saved: 

SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]; 
Export["refraction.gif", Table[Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, r], PlotRange -> 1], {r, 0, 1, .05}]]

Another idea – video embedding is allowed on Facebook. So you can export it to a video, upload through sites like Youtube and then embed it on Facebook.

Comment: just one more question, do you know why (in your code) length slider moves while I move refraction slider (the value of length is not changing, but only slider position changes). Thank you!

Comment: The upper bound of "length" depends on "refraction", you can say its "upper bound us moving" relative to the slider position.

Answer (score 5):

I think your first batch of code looks fine and is easy to place into a `Manipulate`.  I would recommend use of the `PlotRange` option in `Graphics`.

```
R = 10;
n = 1.5;
Manipulate[
  \[Alpha] = ArcSin[H/R];
  p = H/Tan[\[Alpha]];
  \[Beta] = ArcSin[n Sin[\[Alpha]]];
  \[Theta] = \[Beta] - \[Alpha];
  l = H/Tan[\[Theta]];
  Graphics[{
    Line[{{-2, H}, {p, H}}],(*Prism*)
    Circle[{0, 0}, R, {0, Pi/2}], 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 10}}],(*Refracted ray*)
    Line[{{p, H}, {p + l, 0}}],(*Surface*)
    Line[{{0, 0}, {p + l + 10, 0}}]},
    PlotRange -> {{-1,33},{-1,11}}],
  {H,0.0001,6,Appearance->"Labeled"}]
```

Comment: Thank you, you solved my problem. Manipulate is really powerful.